# H is a subgroup of G. Show that a coset of H is not a subgroup of G unless it is equal to H

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I apologize for the basic nature of the question. I’m just still baffled by cosets and I know how important there understanding is in group theory.

Does this just follow from the definition?

Let H be a subgroup of G. A subset of G that can  be written as Hb={hb|h in H} for some b in G is called the right coset.

Clearly the identity coset H=H, i have a hard time seeing how Hb=H for some b in G.

Or maybe I’m misunderstanding the statement?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ . Anyway, a group always contains an identity element.

Comment: $Hb=H$ if $b\in H$.

Comment: Hmm ok, quite basic indeed. Thx

Comment: Note that $Hb=H$ for any $b\in H$, not just for $b=1$. Suppose $b\notin H$. Then $b^{-1}\notin H$ (why not?) and hence $1\notin Hb$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, that meta page froze my chrome browser on my ipad and that has never happened, ever. Anyways is that right click trick only available on a laptop or desktop?